# python\powershell - How to execute powershell multiple line script as a single command?

Tags: python, powershell

I'm trying to execute a powershell script, trying to avoid creating a .ps1 file, I want to run it in a single command, I'm trying  in this way:

```
import os

command='''$jobname = "Recurring PowerShell Task"
$script =  "w32tm /resync"
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "$pshome\powershell.exe" -Argument  "$script"
$duration = ([timeSpan]::maxvalue)
$repeat = (New-TimeSpan -hours 3)
$trigger =New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).Date -RepetitionInterval $repeat -RepetitionDuration $duration

 
$msg = "Enter the username and password that will run the task"; 
$credential = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential("Task username and password",$msg,"$env:userdomain\$env:username",$env:userdomain)
$username = $credential.UserName
$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -StartWhenAvailable -RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable -DontStopOnIdleEnd
 Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $jobname -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -RunLevel Highest -User $username -Password $password -Settings $settings'''

os.system("powershell "+command)
```

but I get error:

```
+ $jobname = Recurring PowerShell Task
+            ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Recurring:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

do you have any advice on how to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: perhaps the concept of powershell scripting is still unclear to me, because I have recently been using it. I apologize in advance for my possible ignorance on the matter

Comment: I have also tried using -Command flag with the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
command = '''$jobname = "Recurring PowerShell Task"
$script =  "w32tm /resync"
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "$pshome\powershell.exe" -Argument  "$script"
$duration = ([timeSpan]::maxvalue)
$repeat = (New-TimeSpan -hours 3)
$trigger =New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).Date -RepetitionInterval $repeat -RepetitionDuration $duration


$msg = "Enter the username and password that will run the task"; 
$credential = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential("Task username and password",$msg,"$env:userdomain\$env:username",$env:userdomain)
$username = $credential.UserName
$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -StartWhenAvailable -RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable -DontStopOnIdleEnd
 Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $jobname -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -RunLevel Highest -User $username -Password $password -Settings $settings'''
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["powershell","/C",command])
# os.system("powershell -EncodedCommand " + b64_command)
```

this uses `subprocess.call` with vectorized arguments (as a list) ... this guarantees that the 3rd argument will be complete ... when you call it normally it messes up on spaces

I struggle to understand why you would prefer this over making a ps1 command script though...

Comment: This has worked using subprocess. Thank you.

Comment: the reason why I don't want to use a ps1 script is that I still know very little, and from what I understand there are "permissions" problems to run, and I would like to be on the safe side

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to avoid creating a .ps1 file?

There’s many different ways you can run this all.

1. You can use a code editor like ISE or VSCode where you can type everything out and then click the `run` button
2. You copy and paste the code into the console window.
3. In the console you can use `invoke-command -ScriptBlock {<your code here>}` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: it seemed the best way, I tried to do `os.system ("powershell Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {" + command + "}")` but it returns me an error for which I would not close the final brace while instead, as you see I include it. I don't know where did the error come from, in any case I solved it in part with Joran's answer, thank you anyway

Comment: Yeah I noticed later that you also had a python tag, so I didn’t even consider that. I was thinking strictly powershell